# How to place 2 items at right using android:layout_toRightOf

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to place one textView at the left and **2** TextView at the Right.

Right now the 2 textview at the right are placed ontop of one another.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytextview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytextview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FOLLOWING"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mytextview1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytextview3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EXPLORE"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mytextview1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

How do I place "mytextview2" and "mytextview3" at the right with space.

Comment: How do I place "mytextview2" and "mytextview3" at the right with space. ,Do you mean arrange vertically or horizontally

Comment: Can you add an image, which you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `mytextview3` at the right using `android:layout_alignParentRight` and then `mytextview2` left of `mytextview3` using `android:layout_toLeftOf`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FOLLOWING"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mytextview3"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextview3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EXPLORE"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="TextView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mytextview3"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="FOLLOWING" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextview3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="EXPLORE" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This way, you will be able to get desired result with lesser effort

Comment: and easy to understand code, like you set 3rd textview to right and set 2nd to the left of 3rd textview

Answer (score 0):

Use below to set view position using `android:layout_toRightOf`. Set `mytextview3` to right of `mytextview2` instead of `mytextview1` and also set the `width` both of the view as `wrap_content`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FOLLOWING"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mytextview1"
        android:gravity="right"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextview3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EXPLORE"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mytextview2"
        android:gravity="right"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```